# Attempt to assign property "team" on bool

Tags: joomla-4.x, sql

I am trying to create a model in Joomla that will display various information pertaining to a certain ID.  When I create the function:

```
public function getItem ($id = null)
{
    if ($this->_item === null)
    {
        $this->_item = false;

        if (empty($id))
        {
            $id = $this->getState('player.id');
        }
        
    }

    $db    = Factory::getDbo();
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);
    $query = "SELECT name FROM #__baseball_teams WHERE id = $id";
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $this->_item = $db->loadObject()->name; 
    
    return $this->_item;
}
```

But when I change the query results from:

```
$this->_item = $db->loadObject()->name;
```

to

```
$this->_item->team = $db->loadObject()->name;
```

I keep getting errors such as `Attempt to assign property "team" on bool`

Or if I try changing things around, I get `Attempt to assign string "team" on null`, etc.

When I run a `print_r`, the data is there and a `var_dump` shows as strings, but I just have no idea why I cannot assign an additional `->` without getting errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, your code is saying that `$this->_item` might be `null` (a non-object) -- if it is, you are overwriting it to be `false` (again, a non-object).  Then, after grabbing your database results, you are trying to assign a property to `$this->_item` as if it was an object, but you cannot assign a property to a non-object.  Perhaps you want to convert a null `$this->_item` to be an empty object so that you can assign properties to it.

Also, you are creating a query object with:
`$query = $db->getQuery(true);`

Then you are overwriting that object with a literal string with:
 `$query = "SELECT name FROM #__baseball_teams WHERE id = $id";`

Instead, let's implement a prepared statement with query building helper methods in J4.

Untested suggestion:

```
public function getItem ($id = null): object
{
    if (!is_object($this->_item))
    {
        $this->_item = (object) [];

        if (!$id)
        {
            $id = $this->getState('player.id');
        }
        
        $db    = JFactory::getDbo();
        $query = $db->getQuery(true);
        $query->select($db->quoteName('name'))
              ->from($db->quoteName('#__baseball_teams'))
              ->where($db->quoteName('id') . ' = :id')
              ->bind(':id', $id);
        $db->setQuery($query);
        $this->_item->name = $db->loadObject()->name; 
    }
    
    return $this->_item;
}
```

From PHP7.4, use the [null coalescing assignment operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59102708/2943403) to replace the `if (!$id) { ... }` condition block.

```
$id ??= $this->getState('player.id');
```

Comment: As usual, you knocked it out of the park.  Thanks for all you do mickmack.